# C - wrong output taking integer numbers from binary file and mmap function

Tags: c, algorithm, file, binaryfiles, mmap

I have some problem about to take integer numbers from binary file. My code is:

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  FILE * fpi, *fpo, *fp;
  int i, len;
  char buf[50];

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf ("Syntax: %s filename_input, filename_output", argv[0]);
    return (1);
  }

  len = 0;
  if ((fpi = fopen (argv[1], "rt")) == NULL)
    perror ("file_input open");
  if ((fpo = fopen (argv[2], "wb")) == NULL)
    perror ("file_output open %");

  while(fscanf(fpi,"%d",&i) != EOF){ //Take the content of file input and put in the file binary
    fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fpo); //I write each number i into file output
  }
  return (0);
}
```

Here, given a txt file with for example 5 integer numbers, it generates the corresponding binary file. Then, if I try to fread  this binary file is all ok, but if I try to read this binary file with mmap function and I put the content on an array, in the output, as content of array, I have a strange character, a small square with 00 02. The code where I use mmap is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int fd;
    int i, n, len;
    int *vet;
    struct stat stat_buf;
    char *paddr;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Syntax: %s filename", argv[0]);
        return (1);
    }

    if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
    }

    if (fstat(fd, &stat_buf) == -1) {
        perror("fstat");
    }

    len = stat_buf.st_size;
    n = len / sizeof(int);

    paddr = mmap((caddr_t) 0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (paddr == (caddr_t) -1) {
        perror("mmap");
    }

    close(fd);

    vet = (int *) paddr;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", vet[i]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

The output that it gives me is:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Showing the actual output you receive would be helpful....

Comment: never used `mmap` before (haven code a commandline app in decades)  but I have a silly suggestion: What size is the file? my bet is you are storing 32bit or bigger integer variables ... and then read them as 8 bit BYTEs ... so some (50%,75% or 87.5%) of the characters will be `0` which some encodings use that for different language page selections ... or it can be also wrongly detected as Unicode ...

Comment: Your code works fine for me using gcc 4.7.3 under Cygwin in Windows 7. Something else must be going on as I cannot figure out how you are getting that character output using `printf("%d")`. Perhaps your shell is somehow interpreting your program's output into Unicode characters, or your program exhibits undefined behaviour somehow. Is this the exact code you are running?

Comment: Also note that you should be returning after each `perror()` call.

Comment: Thank you for answers. @uesp yes, it is the exact code that I run